# WYSIWYG rich text editor without security hazards

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, wysiwyg

- I want rich text editing on my website.
- I don't want to get involved with whitelists to deal with the security hazards posed by the HTML WYSIWYG editors (unless there is a really easy packaged way to do this)
- Markdown is fine, but two panes - one for input
  and one for preview - like SO is not going to work.  It's too 10 years ago.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **I want** `:)` To know what have you tried

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well everything that's out there is these WYSIWYG editors.  The most logical solution is the one SO is using, but for god's sake hasn't someone developed something better in the last five years??  It looks awful now that everyone is using HTML5 and everything is so modern!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always liked [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It's fairly robust and extensible.

Comment: How do you avoid XSS?  As soon as you enable a user to send you html which you intend to display to other users you're opening up a huge can of worms without a whitelist.

Comment: you can scrub it before you send it, but google xss prevention with ckeditor. there's tons of workable/usable solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I found HTML Purifier.  I'll go ahead with one of the WYSIWYG editors and implement this to scrub it before it is dumped into the database.